# Webnovel/light novel where the main character joins a shadow darkness clan and finds armor and swords filled with darkness mana

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I’m looking for the name of this web novel I read years ago and I can’t remember it for the life of me.

From what I can remember, the mc was just a normal person that lived in a backwater town, but a wandering magician found him and he ends up in mountain sect of a shadow/darkness clan.  I remember he was pretty good at swordsmanship, but also pretty efficient in magic.

What I really remember well is two things. The first is that he goes to war against another country, that are all made of warriors, and I remember them being called “hunters”, and when I stopped reading he was infiltrating their ranks.

The second thing that I really remember is that at some point, he was brought into this other world that was completely filled with darkness except for a few places. In this darkness world, he finds like suits of armor and I think swords that are filled with darkness mana that makes them stronger than anything else he could find in his world.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this?

Comment: I’d say around 2021